# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n+1)}{(n^2)(n+1)^2}=1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n+1)}{(n^2)(n+1)^2}$$

The correct answer is 1 but I can't figure out how you end up to this conclusion

Comment: Have you studied simpler sequences before? Have you used the concept of generalizing to $T_r-T_{r-1}$, then cancelling the common terms?

Comment: Hint: TLSCPC.$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2},$$your series is a telescoping series.